# excel ISTEXT returns True where a formula contains the answer ""

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a formula that returns the value "" blank.(correctly) However when testing for ISTEXT, I get the result "True" I understand "" is seen as text, however Im looking to test for actual words that are the alternative outcome ie "Road Finished" or "P&L Item"....what III call real Text. Is there a way around the "" result delivering a True value when tested?

=IF(D46=0,"",IF(K46="Roads Finished","",IF(K46="","no start date",HLOOKUP($D$6,'sales & Con Inputs'!$A$6:$K$98,93)))).....this returns "" correctly

ISTEXT of this cell returns "True" Im looking to use ISTEXT instead of specifying each statement ie Roads Finished ,No Start Date as you see in the forumula above

Comment: You could add an AND condition and an ISBLANK test.

Comment: @wbeard52: Thanks for your help gents much appreciated. Simple solutions to a problem that was doing my head in ....thanks again..TonyH

Comment: Make sure you tick and upvote his answer if it has helped you out!

Comment: @Michael Frank: Im a newbie Michael, how do I tick and upvote?...it was helpful and I am grateful.TonyH

Comment: You should now have the rep to upvote.  You can also click the checkmark to accept the answer if it answers your (original) question.

Comment: Beside his answer you should see something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fSZIV.jpg Just click the up arrow and tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `IF` and `AND` statement.

If the cell to test is in A1.

```
IF(AND(ISTEXT(A1),LEN(A1)>0), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Can this ISTEXT be tested for a range Ie A1:C1.....I dont seem to be able to get this to work? Ive tried using --Istext hoping to count the number of text filled cells the idea being is it >0 then I have text in one of the cells

Comment: I ran out of edit time heres the question.Can this ISTEXT be tested for a range Ie A1:C1.I dont seem to be able to get this to work? Ive tried using --Istext hoping to count the number of text filled cells the idea being is it >0 then I have text in one of the cells formula tried is =IF(--ISTEXT(K46:M46)>0,"Text here","NO TEXT") this always returns No Text even if a cell has a Text answer in it. Ive also tried the same thing with ISBLANK. In effect Im wanting to test 3 cells and if they are blank  "" as the formula answer or have text in them the result is "".Hope that makes sense

Comment: @TonyH: that is actually a different question with a different kind of solution.  The best way to get an answer for that is to ask it as a new question.

Comment: @fixer1234: thank fixer, Im still learning the ropes. I appreciate your advice and patience. Regards TonyH PS is there a guidelines page so I can read up on voting and other protocols?

Comment: @TonyH: Click the help link at the top of any page.  The first few topics cover key general stuff.  A couple of relevant links: http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up, and http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: @wbeard52: Congrats on crossing 2K.

Comment: Is `IF(<stuff>, TRUE, FALSE)` really necessary?